# Save a Layout with Changing values in a loop on sdcard in android

Tags: android

Hi i have a loop which iterates to save a layout with changing values, For every iteration the values in the xml are different and is supposed to be saved when the user click on save button.

```
       String [] sizes = {"A","B","C","D"};
        for (int i = 0; i <= sizes.length-1 ; i++){
            try {
                String x = sizes[i];
                Intent intents = new Intent();
                intents.setClass(Sizes.this, Sizes.class);

                Bundle bundles = new Bundle();
                bundles.putCharSequence("sizes", x);
                intents.putExtras(bundles);
                startActivity(intents);
                doSave();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Every size loads different values and i need to save the layouts for all the values in the loop on the sdcard. My doSave():

```
         public void doSave() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    RelativeLayout imagevw =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sizelayout);
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(imagevw.getWidth(), imagevw.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    int weight,height;

    weight =  imagevw.getWidth();

    height =  imagevw.getHeight();

    Bitmap cs = Bitmap.createBitmap(weight, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(cs);

    c.drawBitmap(b,0,0,null);

    imagevw.draw(c);

    String getDirPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
    File myDirPath = new File(getDirPath +"/Size");

    if(!myDirPath.exists()){

        myDirPath.mkdir();

    }

    File file1 = new File("/sdcard/size/"+size+"saved image.png");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file1);

if (fos != null) {

cs.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);

fos.close();
    }

    }
```

When u save a single layout it saves well. The problem is when the loop completes it only saves the current layout with the current values before you click on save button. Meaning it is saving only the present layout. How can save a layout for each loop because they have different values. Note the "***size***+"saved image.png" ***size*** is a bundle in that instance.

Comment: What is `saved` in "File file1 = new File("/sdcard/size/size+"saved image.png");"?And there is an error in balancing on quotes in that statement.

Comment: Sorry I have edited it that was a mistake while copying. Any ideas on how i can go about it

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you call `doSave();` without changing value of `size`.So all files save with  the same name in the same path and so each file replace old file with that name and finally the latest one remains.

Comment: size is the bundle that holds the title that is displayed. That is when the array starts with A ,the value of A is assigned to size, when its B that value is assigned to size. Thus size will have different values for each iteration. The result i get is not for the last size but for the present size before i click on save. meaning it is not saving when iterating the array because i would be having the last size as my result if it is overwriting the previous one. Thanks for your reply